# Typescript: Overloads with optional parameters not working when strictNullChecks is enabled

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using a combination of generics and overloads to type a class but am having issues with the optional parameter in my overload when `strictNullChecks` are enabled. How can I get this to work with `strictNullChecks` enabled?

A simple example test case fails with "Argument of type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'." only when `strictNullChecks` is enabled:

```
class BaseClass { }
class BaseClass2 { }

class Test<T extends BaseClass, R extends BaseClass2> {
    test(a: T): R;
    test(a?: undefined): undefined;
    test(a?: any) {
        return a;
    }

    test2(b?: T) {
        // Errors only when strictNullChecks is enabled (can be switched on in the options tab above)
        return this.test(b) 
    }
}

const testClass = new Test<BaseClass, BaseClass2>()

// desired ouput
const output1: undefined = testClass.test2()
const output2: BaseClass2 = testClass.test2(new BaseClass())
```

Or in the typescript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20BaseClass%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20BaseClass2%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%3CT%20extends%20BaseClass%2C%20R%20extends%20BaseClass2%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testM(a%3A%20T%20%7C%20undefined%2C%20b%3A%20R)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20b%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testM2(d%3A%20R%2C%20c%3F%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.testM(c%2C%20d)%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test%3CBaseClass%2C%20BaseClass2%3E()%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20output1%3A%20undefined%20%3D%20test.testM2(new%20BaseClass2()%2C%20undefined)%0D%0Aconst%20output2%3A%20BaseClass2%20%3D%20test.testM2(new%20BaseClass2()%2C%20new%20BaseClass())

EDIT (25 June 2019 14:20): Update the code snippet to reflect the desired type output

Comment: You should be able to do this with a conditional type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correct and well defined consequence of enabling `--strictNullChecks`.

TypeScript's designer, Anders Hejlsberg explains it wonderfully in [this talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B881). It's in the last 3rd but it is absolutely worth watching the entire talk.

In short, `--strictNullChecks`. Changes the relationship between types such that the  values `null` and `undefined` are each members of two new singleton types `null` and `undefined` and are no longer constituents of any other types.

Therefore, given `T | undefined`, the first signature

```
test(a: T)
```

is no longer a candidate. Furthermore, and critically, the second signature

```
test(a: undefined)
```

Is no longer a candidate either because it the argument could be a `T` and a `T` is not an `undefined`.

Fortunately, the solution is actually less code and easier to understand

```
test(a: T | undefined) {
    return something;
}
```

The union type expresses that `a` is a member of the set of all possible values that belong to the union of the type `T` and the type `undefined`.

A key difference between single signature taking union type of all possible parameter types and a set of distinct overload signatures is correlation of parameter and return types.

Specifically,

```
declare function f(x: A): B;
declare function f(x: T): U;
```

Is not equivalent to

```
declare function f(x: A | T): B | U;
```

being different in terms of both what it accepts and what it rejects. See this [playground](https://fabiandev.github.io/typescript-playground/#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) as an example.

However, absent `--strictNullChecks`, the overloads were only meaningful when using a value that was known to be exactly `undefined` because every `T` is implicitly `T | undefined`.

You can return to using overloads and thereby regain control of parameter type to return type correlation but only by introducing additional information at the call site like

```
test2(b?: T) {
    if (b) { 
      return this.test(b);
    } else {
      return this.test(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! For each case `T` or `undefined` I'd like to define a unique return type, hence the use of overloads in the original case. Is this possible?

Comment: Edited the original post to show the desired output typing.